# Relating the eigenspaces of the complex structure induced on the dual to the dual of the eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-geometry

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb R$ and let $J$ be an almost complex structure on $V$. Consider the complexification $V_\mathbb C:= V \otimes_\mathbb R \mathbb C$ and the extension of $J$ to $V_\mathbb C$ as a $\mathbb C$-linear map, thus having eigenvalues $\pm i$. Let $V^{0,1}, V^{1,0} \subset V_\mathbb C$ be the corresponding eigenspaces.

In Wells, "Differential analysis on complex manifolds", Chapter I.3, p32., $(V^*)^{(1,0)}$ is defined as the $\mathbb C$-dual of $V^{1,0}$ (similarly for $(V^*)^{0,1}$).

My first question is, does this mean $(V^*)^{(1,0)} = Hom_{\mathbb R}(V^{1,0}, \mathbb C)$, or does it mean $(V^*)^{1,0} = Hom_{\mathbb C}(V^{1,0}, \mathbb C)$? What is typically taken to be the definition?

Consider also the complex structure $J$ on $(V_\mathbb C)^*:= Hom_{\mathbb C}(V_\mathbb C, \mathbb C)$ defined as $(J\alpha)(v):= \alpha(Jv)$; again, I'm assuming we take $\mathbb C$-linear maps, not just $\mathbb R$-linear ones (is this correct?). Now, the $J$ on $(V_\mathbb C)^*$ also has two eigenspaces corresponding to $\pm i$, which I will call $W^{1,0}$ and $W^{0,1}$.

My main question is, how does $(V^*)^{(1,0)}$ relate to the eigenspace $W^{1,0}$? Intuitively, they should of course coincide. But what would be a rigorous proof for this?

Comment: They are the $\pm i$-eigenspaces, not $\pm 1$. Quite an important difference.

Comment: @QuaereVerum Sorry, that is what I meant, my brain slipped.

Comment: Okay. Anyway, the answer is: $(V^*)^{(1,0)}=\text{Hom}_\mathbb{C}(V^{(1,0)},\mathbb{C})$, where one views $V^{(1,0)}$ as a complex vector space with complex multiplication defined by the linear map $J$. This is why one needs to complexify and then consider the $i$-eigenspace. If we looked at $\mathbb{R}$-linear maps, we would get real dimension $2\dim_\mathbb{R}V$ for this dual space, which is evidently not what we want.

Comment: Thank you. Isn't the complex multiplication on $(V^*)^{(1,0)}$ given by the restriction of the complex multiplication on $V_\mathbb C$, though? (Where in turn, the complex multiplication on $V_\mathbb C$ is given by the isomorphism $V_\mathbb C \simeq V \oplus i V$, which is independent of $J$).

And what about my main question?

Comment: The answer is that they're the same, as you already suggested. If you, or someone else, wants to write out the details, feel free! I just wanted to give you the answer to the question. Figuring out the details would be a good exercise. You can also check Huybrechts's book "Complex Geometry".